# Unable to send parameters in @html.actionlink to partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views, html.actionlink

I have one actionlink inside the `foreach` loop. Depending on the model items I am generating link buttons with values dynamically.
This is how it looks

```
@foreach (var group in Model.records)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(@group.clientId.ToString(), "detailsbyClientId", "DocumentVerification", new { id = @group.clientId.ToString()},null)</td>
        <td>@group.clientName</td>
        <td>@group.Count</td>
    </tr>
}
```

On clicking link button i am calling partial view as below.

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult detailsbyClientId(int? clientId)
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

I am receiving a `null` value for `clientId` but `@group.clientId.ToString()` contains a valid value.

Comment: You creating a query string value named `id` but the parameter in your method is `clientId` - change one or the other so they match

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. Pls put answer

Comment: @NIRANJANG It's a typo, not an answer. We have a close reason specifically for questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter in your method is named `clientId` but your generating a query string value named `id`. Change one or the other to match

```
public PartialViewResult detailsbyClientId(int? ID)
{
    ....
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.ActionLink(@group.clientId.ToString(), "detailsbyClientId", "DocumentVerification", new { id = group.clientId },null)
```

Note you do not need the `@` nor `.ToString()` in the 4th parameter - just `new { id = group.clientId }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The point is the name of the variable you are passing and the name of the variable that is expecting the value in the controller should be the same.

```
 @foreach (var group in Model.records)
 {
   <tr>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink(@group.clientId.ToString(), "detailsbyClientId", "DocumentVerification", new { clientId = group.clientId},null)</td>
    <td>@group.clientName</td>
    <td>@group.Count</td>
  </tr>
 }

 [HttpGet]
 public PartialViewResult detailsbyClientId(int? clientId)
 {
    return PartialView();
 }
```